# Launch django server from ide with virtualenv

Tags: django

I"m trying to launch the django server via and IDE (pycharm) via the pycharm gulp tool.

The gulp task to run the server is:

```
// Run django server
gulp.task('runServer', function() {
  exec('python manage.py runserver', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });
});
```

However although this works fine from the command line it doesn't work within pycharm using the gulp tool.  I get the error below for not activating the virtualenv first.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

Is there a way to activate the virtualenv before running the django server with the gulp tool in pycharm (without breaking it from working in the command line)?

Comment: You need to point your Pycharm Python interpreter to the interpreter in your virtualenv in the settings.

Comment: Instead of `python` use `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python` for example.

Comment: Thanks (pycharm was already pointing to the interpreter) but changing the gulp file to use `/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python` fixed it.